# sudo apt-get update returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: apt

After 20 years+ of using UNIX/Linux, I don't mind admitting that the problem described below has beaten me.

I run Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and I try to ensure that updates are installed every week. But around 2nd October, thing started to go wrong, and I've no idea how to resolve it.

Running 'sudo apt-get update' returns:

```
chrish@chrish-2018:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done                         
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Googling various bits of this output returns some hits, including other posts on askubuntu, but I've yet to find a solution for my particular problem.

Can anyone help?

Any assistance will be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Hmmm. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it hits the same IP address...and works. Are you on an enterprise network or otherwise using some sort of proxy?

Comment: Using `sudo software-properties-gtk` please try another provider in the first tab "download from" check box

Comment: Thanks both for your comments.
Regarding the network, the machine in question is my home PC directly connected to ADSL, so there is no proxy. Regarding choosing another provider, I can do that and select the UK server, but I still end up with the same error. It is such a strange issue!

Comment: There are some other things you can try. Try `sudo aptitude update` instead. Secondly, you can try updating with Synaptic Package Manager. You might have to install aptitude and synaptic if they are not installed.

Comment: Thanks again Raffles. The solution in the end was to simply restart my broadband hub(!), which is just bizarre, given that my ubuntu box was fully connected to the internet beforehand, and there were no obvious network problems. It does however concur with a report of an identical problem posted on another forum - the author of that post stated that the issue fixed itself a couple of days later, without them making any changes to ubuntu. At least I'll know what to do next time!