# Errors sudo apt-get update and unable to install packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates

I have several errors when running `sudo apt-get update` for a few weeks. As of today, I am unable to install packages using 'sudo apt install'. I've been trying to find solutions to resolve these issues online, but with no success so far, so I hope you see what the problem is. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here are the errors returned when using "apt-get update":

```
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And here is an example of the error returned when I run `sudo apt install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openconnect
```

Comment: Please run `sudo software-properties-gtk` and in the first tab`Ubuntu Software` you can try another provider, and in the second tab `Other software` , uncheck everything. Once you have done this, try `sudo apt-get update` again and edit the results into your question.

Comment: Thank you @Raffles for your response. I modified in `Ubuntu Software` the downloading from United Kingdom to Main server, and unchecked everything in the tab `Other software`. The results of `sudo apt-get update` are updated into my question.

Comment: Someone else had a [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488738/sudo-apt-get-update-returns-400-bad-request) 2 weeks ago. Try restarting your Wifi and let us know if it helps.